# Using jquery to determine if any elements within a div was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I tell using jQuery if an any element within a div (panel1) was clicked?  I have this piece of code that I use to show/hide a popup:

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') == 'link1') {
            $('#panel1').show();
        } else {
            $('#panel1').hide();
        }
    });
```

The problem is that the popup (panel1) gets dismissed if I click on any control/element within panel1.  I'd like to keep panel1 open unless an area outside panel1 is clicked (or if link1 is clicked again).  How can I revise this code to achieve this?  Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#panel1').click(function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       //Other code if you want to execute anything on panel click.
    });

$('body').click(function (e) {
       if($("#panel1").is(":visible")) 
          $('#panel1').hide();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @ShankarSangoli.  I needed my original code as well to activate the popup, but combined with this code, it works as I want it.

Answer (score 1):

Make a following html markup:

```
<body>
<div id="div1">
... all the body content here
</div>
<div id="panel1">
</div>
```

I suppose the popup #panel1 is positioned out of normal flow anyway, so it is no problem.
Then in jquery use div1 instead of body and that's it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') == 'link1') {
            $('#panel1').show();
        } else if($(e.target).attr('id') != 'panel1') {
           $('#panel1').hide();
        }
    });
```